# Optimize SQL Server Stored Procedure further

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, race-condition

How can I optimize / refactor this stored procedure further?

Where are the performance improvements to be had?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE cc_test_setnumber
    @UUID AS VARCHAR(50),
    @Status AS VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE    

    IF @Status = 'ACTIVE'  
    BEGIN
       DECLARE @Tbl AS TABLE (UUID VARCHAR(50))

       BEGIN TRANSACTION 

       UPDATE dbo.cc_testagents 
       SET Status = 'INCALL', LastUpdated = GETDATE() 
       OUTPUT INSERTED.UUID INTO @Tbl
       WHERE ID = (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM dbo.cc_testagents WHERE Status = 'IDLE')    

       UPDATE cc_testnumbers 
       SET Status = 'ACTIVE', 
           AgentUUID = (SELECT UUID FROM @Tbl) 
       OUTPUT INSERTED.AgentUUID AS 'UUID'
       WHERE CallUUID = @UUID   

       COMMIT TRANSACTION
END  
ELSE --BUSY, WRAPUP, NOANSWER, NOAGENT
BEGIN      
       UPDATE dbo.cc_testagents  
       SET Status = 'WRAPUP' 
       WHERE UUID = (SELECT AgentUUID FROM dbo.cc_testnumbers WHERE CallUUID = @UUID)

       SELECT @Status = REPLACE(@Status, 'NOAGENT', 'IDLE')

       UPDATE dbo.cc_testnumbers 
       SET Status = @Status, CallUUID = '' 
       WHERE CallUUID = @UUID
    END 
END
```

Comment: If this is your code, and the best you can think, this should be asked in [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site. Or are you asking about how to optimize SPs in general?

Answer (score 0):

In sql server management studio the "database engine tuning advisor" is a good place to start- not only for this stored proc but for any other query running against these tables.

It's hard to give you a specific recommendation without knowing a bit more about the table structure and the other queries that are contending for locks on these tables.  Make sure there's a clustered/nonclustered index on cc_testagents.ID, cc_testagents.uuid, cc_testnumbers.CallUUID.

If you're experiencing deadlock issues and there are queries reading from cc_testagents/cc_testnumbers that can tolerate reading uncommitted data a quick and dirty "fix" is to use the nolock hint / set transaction isolation level read uncommitted on those select statements. *Depending on who you ask this is considered bad practice, just throwing it out there as something that might hold you over if you have some crippling deadlock issues in production.*